# Which hardware for Machine Learning software?

Tags: software

I would like to build a desktop PC with Linux and use it mainly for machine learning research and related stuff. I am aware that there are software packages that use GPU "magic stuff" to train statistical models on GPUs. However, my knowledge in hardware is very poor. I don't want to buy hardware that doesn't support machine learning software.

Questions:

1- does it matter what CPU one buys? AMD, Intel?

2- does it matter what graphics card one buys? nVidia, ATI?

3- does it matter what motherboard? does it have to contain certain ports/features?

Comment: I think this might be *just* barely on-topic because of the GPU part--nVidia/CUDA seem like a much better choice for GPGPU-related machine learning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The choice of CPU doesn't matter much, beyond the obvious. More and faster cores are better, as are larger caches; these are, unfortunately, also more expensive. 
Similarly, motherboards don't matter much except that it'll need to support everything you want (lots of RAM, fast ethernet, etc).

As for a graphics card, there are a few general-purpose GPU (GPGPU) computing platforms. Until recently, nVIDIA's **CUDA** platform has been the clear winner, particularly for deep learning. nVidia distribute [some deep learning libraries](https://developer.nvidia.com/deep-learning-software) themselves. Some other popular deep learning packages, like [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/get_started/os_setup.html#optional-linux-enable-gpu-support), [Theano](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/using_gpu.html) and [Caffe](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/installation.html) also only support CUDA on the GPU. Matlab's GPU computing is also limited to CUDA-compatible video cards.  **OpenCL** is the other major alternative, and has historically lagged quite a bit behind. However, there are efforts to port Theano and Caffe to OpenCL. R and Python bindings also exist for OpenCL too.  As of early 2016, CUDA still seems to be the field's first choice, but if you got a terrific deal on a beefy AMD GPU, you might want to think about it.

In either event, you'll need a sufficiently large power supply and cooling. Some of the high-end GPUs draw 200+ watts at full load.

---

If you're really hard-pressed for speed, Intel's C++ compiler can occasionally generate slightly faster code for Intel CPUs, but in practice this would requires writing in C++ (and it's usually not a huge difference). Intel does sell the [Xeon Phi](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/xeon/xeon-phi-detail.html) co-processor. If you're going to use that, you probably want to stay with other Intel gear.